# Need help building automated control of inline fan from range hood power

Tags: electrical, fans

As part of a home remodel, I'm designing a make-up air system that will serve to replenish our kitchen when the 1100 CFM (variable speed) range hood is operating. Due to the higher output of the exhaust (to meet code, comfortable environment, etc.), I'm planning to run a variable speed inline fan that will bring filtered make-up air in from outside and into the toe kick below the range top (I don't have a good way to do it from the ceiling in front of the range unfortunately). The fresh air will be sucked up over the range, mix with the kitchen air and mostly go right out the vent hood.  I plan to run the inline lower than the exhaust to maintain negative pressure. Want to avoid as much of that not tempered air making its way in the rest of the kitchen/house.

**Scenarios to consider:**

1. When the vent hood is on the first 2 settings it is running under 400 CFM and doesn't really need make-up air. The fan should not kick on/damper does not open - Nothing to trigger in the make-up air system i.e. won't be connected to the switch/control at all.
2. When on the most commonly used medium power settings. Lets say setting 3 and 4,  I'd like to kick on the make-up air at low or medium power. No user intervention required. This could be via whatever sort of switch/build needed.
3. When you need to crank it up to level 5 or 6, it triggers high/full power on the variable control. There could also be a switch, dial, etc. to adjust the inline fan speed located at the range, but not required.

In summary 1 & 2 = Do nothing, 3 = Low, 4 = Medium, 5 or 6 = High

The range hood company provided me with this mediocre electrical diagram. I'm looking for input on feasibility before I pull the trigger on the hood. From my untrained eyes I see 1-6 labeled on the blower wires and should be able to differentiate a power signal between the different speed settings on the blower. Hopefully relaying that to trigger an aligned speed on the inline fan.

**How would you propose wiring this? I don't have much electrical experience on the types of switches etc. that could be used. I've done some research into a variable resistor controlled PWM to drive the fan, and that seems promising. What type of variable resistor could I marry these 1-6 settings to 3 levels of voltage for the PWM? I'm open to any way of making this work! Products involved listed below and appreciate anyone's help!**

- ProLine Range Hood 750 + Diagram their support provided attached via image
- Basic Covert 10" Inline Fan, 810 CFM SKU #: VT-IFCTFAN-10 or can do a smart controlled AC Infinity T10 Inline Fan with Variable Speed Controller
- A damper that just needs a signal to open in conjunction with the fan kicking on
- Ex. Honeywell Damper

[image: Electrical diagram from range hood vendor]

Comment: Won't passive make-up air work for this? You'd certainly lose more indoor air that way, but it's a simple alternative. The intake duct would need to be fairly large, though, to minimize the pressure drop.

Comment: Yes, for running any exhaust under ~600 pretty much passive air should work. For running at 1100 though on a newer and pretty sealed build we’ll definitely see a significant pressure drop. 

I proposed passive air, a few HVAC friends said we should bring in forced air plus code requirements to meet. I think something like 700 CFM will be plenty to have a comfortable environment and no pressure issues.

As for this setup I’m stuck on how to translate the positive current on the 1-6 wires to settings on a rheostat or something like that which could control the speed of the inline fan.

Comment: Interesting that the [electronics.se] guys bounced this here - seems more in their realm. Anyway... I'd assume that you'd wire the output of pins 3 & 4 to the low speed on your blower, and pins 5 & 6 to the high speed on your blower. You'd probably need diodes in there to prevent current from back flowing to the "other" pin (don't want power on pin 4 when it should only be on 3). Then, whenever the blower is on, open the damper. <-- sounds like EE, not DIY to me...

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan -- That was my thought too. I'm expecting something like AC Current detecting switches that trigger the right resistors and ultimately send the appropriate power to the fan via PWM, voltage reduction, etc. Essentially a custom circuit that needs EE input from my standpoint.

Comment: Maybe rephrase the question over there but leave out key phrases like "remodel", "range hood", "make up air", and just leave it as an electronics control project. "I need to turn on B when power is applied to A". ;)

Comment: @No-Reservations - I'm the EE.SE mod who migrated this to here because IMHO it seemed to be asking for *domain-specific* (i.e. home appliance) knowledge which is off-topic at EE.SE. Asking about things like range hood wiring usually either fails and the question gets closed as a "usage" question; or it gets flagged for migration to here at DIY.SE, - it says in the on-topic page this is the place for questions that would be asked of a home contractor. So, while I dislike the condescending "interesting that..."  part of the comment from *FreeMan*, we'll see what happens if you migrate it back.

Comment: Thanks all! I'll meet in the middle and re-write this completely directed towards the electrical circuitry side. I've learned a lot in the last day and can probably phrase this in a much more on target way for that page now.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/628470/circuit-design-help-for-automating-fan-from-another-device